# Android Studio: Remember opened files after restart

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

How to make Android Studio remember opened files/tabs after close Android Studio and then start Android Studio again? Is there any option to remember workspace?

Comment: close exit android studio then shutdown... dont forcefully shutdown android studio will automatically remember..

Comment: yes I mean just close android studio and then start android studio

Answer (score 0):

Before shutdown Just leave it open(tab/file) then exit android studio (Not close project) , so after start android studio again has opened tab will be restored

Comment: this do not work for me, maybe it is disabled in options but I do not know where to enable it again

Comment: Turn off Power Save Mode option in File Tab first , then if you think  make changes in setting , you can Restart Android studio